# how to convert or cast CString to LPWSTR?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I tried to use this code:

```
USES_CONVERSION;
LPWSTR temp = A2W(selectedFileName);
```

but when I check the `temp` variable, just get the first character

thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an ANSI or Unicode build?

Comment: Your description of the problem is very narrow. Please explain what you're trying to do and what the variable hold.

Comment: Is `selectedFileName` a `CStringA` or a `CStringW`?

Comment: i really don't know if is ANSI or UniCode, i'm C# programer, and now i'm in troubles with C++... I have a project in VS2012 with C + + as a language, the project compiles an OCX which is embedded into a web page.
From the page invoking existing functions in the OCX.
in this particular case, a function that should raise a dialog box, and select a file, which must return (as a string) to the website.
in the OCX Map definitions i only can specify sentences like LPWSTR or LPCTSTR, but not a simple type like CString. As I said before I am new to C + +.
so I need to convert a CString to LPWSTR

Comment: CString wraps LPTSTR, CStringW wraps LPWSTR, CStringA wraps LPSTR.  If you have a CString, and need to pass it to a function that takes LPCTSTR, just pass it.  CString has an implicit conversion to LPCTSTR.

Answer (score 8):

If I recall correctly, `CString` is typedef'd to either `CStringA` or `CStringW`, depending on whether you're building Unicode or not.

`LPWSTR` is a "Long Pointer to a Wide STRing" -- aka: `wchar_t*`

If you want to pass a `CString` to a function that takes `LPWSTR`, you can do:

```
some_function(LPWSTR str);

// if building in unicode:
some_function(selectedFileName);

// if building in ansi:
some_function(CA2W(selectedFileName));

// The better way, especially if you're building in both string types:
some_function(CT2W(selectedFileName));
```

**HOWEVER**  `LPWSTR` is non-const access to a string.  Are you using a function that tries to modify the string?  If so, you want to use an actual buffer, not a `CString`.

Also, when you "check" `temp` -- what do you mean?  did you try `cout << temp`?  Because that won't work (it will display just the first character):

`char` uses one byte per character.  `wchar_t` uses two bytes per character.  For plain english, when you convert it to wide strings, it uses the same bytes as the original string, but each character gets padded with a zero.  Since the `NULL` terminator is also a zero, if you use a poor debugger or cout (which is uses ANSI text), you will only see the first character.

If you want to print a wide string to standard out, use `wcout`.

Comment: Hi, thnank for u reply..I meant that in the function that is called from the web page, I get only the first character of the string (in this case the selected file) that's ,the letter 'C' which is the drive from which I am getting the name of the archive.
apparently to convert CString to LPWSTR lost the rest of the string

Comment: @Luis I doubt that anything got lost. It's just that you don't understand what how a UNICODE string is encoded in Windows. Make sure to read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html). When done you will understand the why the different [Format Specifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/75w45ekt.aspx) are required for strings. You should use `su`.

Comment: UNICODE: CString cstring = "some"; LPWSTR lpwstr = cstring .GetBuffer(cstring .GetLength());

Comment: MULTICHAR: CString cstring = "some"; LPWSTR lpwstr = CT2W(cstring);

Answer (score 1):

In short: You cannot. If you need a non-const pointer to the underlying character buffer of a `CString` object you need to call [`GetBuffer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt26tkzx.aspx).

If you need a **const** pointer you can simply use `static_cast<LPCWSTR>(selectedFilename)`.

Comment: The cast only works if the program is built with the `UNICODE` flag, which maps `TCHAR` to `wchar_t`.  If that flag is not turned on, it is a `char`, so doing a static cast will not give you what you want.  Since `CString` has an overload for `operator LPCTSTR()`, there is no need to use `static_cast` - it will do the conversion implicitly.

Comment: @Zac You are totally awesomely clever. Thanks for pointing out the obvious. And failing to be correct as well... [`CStringT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bzxfsea.aspx) does not have an `operator LPCTSTR()` *overload*. And its base class `CSimpleStringT` has [`operator PCXSTR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk1z2hd9.aspx) defined. Whether or not a `static_cast` is required is a matter of compiler warning level and build tool sets. Feel free to omit it.

Comment: In your effort to pick a fight, you completely missed the point.  `LPCTSTR` = "long pointer to a constant t-string".  `PCXSTR` = "pointer to a const x-string" where the `x` is filled in based on the template parameter declared with the `CSimpleString<>`.  That is, if UNICODE is not defined, `CString` is basically a `CSimpleString<char>`, so trying to use `static_cast<LPCWSTR>` will not work, which is what you left out, and which is what I was pointing out.

Comment: @Zac In all your awesomeness, why don't you provide your own answer then? I mean, give **me** a chance to downvote yours without a reason. It's only fair, no?

Comment: I down-voted yours because it is not complete.  I went on to describe how you can fix it.  You seem to take things personally which makes it difficult to see that (unlike you), I wasn't attacking you, but noting what you needed to add to fix it.  Since Tim has already posted an answer that is complete, there is no need for me to re-post what is already written and correct.  But feel free to down-vote his post if you feel yours is better.

Comment: @Zac I'm not taking this personal. It's just very obvious that you downvoted this answer as an act of revenge. If an answer is incomplete then it may not get my vote. With Visual Studio 2013 removing MBCS support for MFC altogether your point may not even hold. As a general guideline, downvotes should be used on answers that are [complete and utter bogus](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18859332/1889329).

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a decently old question, but I had this same question and none of the previous answers worked for me.

This, however, did work for my unicode build:

```
LPWSTR temp = (LPWSTR)(LPCWSTR)selectedFileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

LPWSTR is a "Long Pointer to a Wide String". It is like wchar*.

```
CString strTmp = "temp";
wchar* szTmp;
szTmp = new WCHAR[wcslen(strTmp) + 1];
wcscpy_s(szTmp, wcslen(strTmp) + 1, strTmp);
```